# TestNG: Test names in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, testng

Suppose I have a simple test like so:

```
public class SimpleTestFactory {
    private int instanceNumber;

    @Factory(dataProvider="provideTestData")
    public SimpleTestFactory(int instanceNumber) {
        this.instanceNumber = instanceNumber;
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] provideTestData() { return new Object[][] {{1},{2}}; }

    @Test
    public void testOne() { System.out.printf("Test 1, Instance %d%n", instanceNumber); }
}
```

When I run this in Eclipse, I get only one entry instead of two in the "all tests" tab; both test instances are "grouped together" under `SimpleTestFactory` -> `testOne()`.  Furthermore, say that there is an if-block in `testOne()` that fails instance 2.  Then, the results in the "all tests" tab, it may show (depending on whether instance 1 or instance 2 is first) a test passing with a stack trace or a test failing with no stack trace, as if the result of one instance is overwriting another.

How can I get it so that the two instances are shown separately?  That is, I get something like `SimpleTestFactory[1]` -> `testOne()` and `SimpleTestFactory[2]` -> `testOne()`?  What if I add in a second test, `testTwo()`?

Answer (score 0):

Have your test implement `org.testng.ITest` and override `getName()` to return the name of the instance.

Comment: Suppose I do so, and `getName()` returns `instanceNumber` as a `String`.  Suppose I also have a second test method, `testTwo()`.  If I run it in Eclipse, all I see is `instanceNumber` without any reference to `testOne()` or `testTwo()`.  So, now I have the converse problem of knowing which instance had a failing test, but not which test had failed.

Comment: Also, it appears that `getName()` is not part of the `ITest` interface; I was referring to `getTestName()` here.